# Node require syntax

Tags: node.js

I am new to Javascript and even newer to Node. I am trying to read an express server code and can't figure out following line in my app.js file:

```
module.require('./auth')(passport);
```

I know I have a variable that holds passport module in app.js:

```
var passport = require('passport');
```

and I also have auth.js in the same directory which exports the following function:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email'
    }, function(idpEmail, password, done) {
        // do email mapping
        findEmailFromDummyDb(idpEmail, password,function(err,user){
            if(err) {
                done(null, false, {
                    messages: err.toString()
                });
            } else {
                done(null, {
                    sysEmail: user.sysEmail
                });
            }
        });
    }));
```

However, what does following function actually do?

```
module.require('./auth')(passport);
```

Comment: Think of it as dependency injection

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Why are the answers downvoted. Is anyone moderating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module.require('./auth')` imports a function, then it get's called with `passport` as a parameter. It's the same as

```
const auth = require('./auth');
const passport = require('passport');
auth = auth(passport);
```

Comment: Hello baao, thanks for your response. I get it now. I have a follow up question. What will happen if there are two functions in my auth.js and both takes passport as the parameter? Which one will be called in this situation?

Comment: That's not possible, only one can be exported as the function you are calling. However, in any coincidence, the last one assigned will be called in case you're exporting a object. But that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The below returns a javascript function.

```
module.require('./auth');
```

You are then immediately calling the function with the passport object as a function argument.

```
(passport)
```